# Converting java Date into Javascript Date

Tags: java, javascript, json, date

I have a map.I am converting the Map into a JSON Object.I am reading the JSON object and want to convert it into a Javascript date.

The Date object I send is read as  2012-12-19T06:00:00.000+0000 in js and I do not understand what is the T in this String.Anyone can throw light on this

Comment: t for timezone I guess, use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: the time format is ISO-8601. `T` is time delimiter, read more at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 ( section: Combined date and time representations )

Comment: Modern browsers will parse the string correctly if you change the offset (+0000) to +00:00(Though if it is always 0 offset, use 'Z' instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a string representation of a date as per the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specification. Here `T` stands for the beginning of the time portion of the datetime representation.

You can convert this representation to javascript date object using `new Date('2012-12-19T06:00:00.000+0000')`.

You can use a regex to get only the date portion. The regex `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.exec('2012-12-19T06:00:00.000+0000')[0]` will give you the date portion alone.

Refer
    [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: how to get the Date alone ?

Comment: @Harish: What do you have if not the Date, do you have a string? Please show us your code

Comment: I got the solution.YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Answer (score 4):

The "T" is part of the ISO 8601 serialisation of the date, which is the [JavaScript Date String Format](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15).

Answer (score 2):

in java format the date to string the following simple date formatter

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d y H:m:s ZZZ");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date());
```

In java script side use

```
new Date(dateString)
```